# URL to open a list element in dialog box on a specific site?

Tags: list, list-form, url, display-form

I have a link (`https://mysite/tools/EmployeeList/Lists/Zutrittsberechtigung/DispForm.aspx?ID=284`) that is sent per E-Mail. This link opens a list element in it's DispForm.aspx:

[image: DispForm]

The user wants this list element to open on another site, that is: (`https://mysite/tools/EmployeeList/SitePages/StartEL.aspx`)

I can open the element when I go to that site, but **I don't know what to write in the link** to open it in such a way, because the HTTPS link doesn't change when I open the list element)

[image: Element]

Can someone tell me if this is possible and what kind of link I have to use to open the list element on that site?(`https://mysite/tools/EmployeeList/SitePages/StartEL.aspx`)

Comment: What do you mean by "The user wants this list element to open on another site"??

Comment: @GaneshSanap The user gets a link via Nintex Workflow. He wants the link to change to open the list item on that site he requested

Comment: Nintex is just sending a link to the list items location, so if you want the URL to be different you would have to move the List to that URL and reconfigure the Workflow on the new list.  I'm guessing that the StartEL.aspx page has a list view webpart of the list in question and that is where the confusion is coming from.  The link that Nintex is sending is to the actual list item, not to the page that is displaying the list.  I don't think that there is away around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simpler than I thought, the URL I had to use was just

https://mysite/tools/EmployeeList/SitePages/StartEL.aspx?&launch=ID&launchlist=Zutrittsberechtigung&launchmode=disp

Note that ID needs to be specified in the Nintex Workflow.